# Dropdown menu doesn't appear when container overflow-x: scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create multiple dropdown and scroll to reach all dropdown but dropdown menu is invisible in React project  When I open dropdown I see DropdownItems is in here from GoogleChrome inspect but it is invisible.

```
DropdownItems(dropdown menu) => position:absolute
DropdownBase => position: relative
```

```
MultipleButtonContainer => overflow-x: scroll
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6OlH.gif)